# Select date via the calendar cannot typping in

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I had link a html type text to jqueryui datepicker.
I only want user select date via the calendar not typping in, any function can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `readonly` attribute on your text input like this:

```
<input type='text' id='foo' readonly='true'>
```